# Android - Draw a line on a bitmap is being drawn on other spot

Tags: android, android-bitmap, ontouch

I'm creating image editor for Android, the app will contain some features which one of them is drawing a line (size and color of the brush are not matter).

I have already made the lines but there seems to be an issue with either the onTouchEvent or the initial of the bitmap.

The flow goes as following:
User press a button->user pick a picture from gallery->image is being loaded to a ImageView and being modified as a bitmap

The issue is:
While attempting to draw a line in the screen, the touch event is being "cornered" to a specific spot on the app, as seen on the linked picture below:
https://www.imageupload.net/image/error.xlbW5

Now to show some code..
Here is how I defined my ImageView (nothing out of the ordinary):

```
    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="500dp"
        android:id="@+id/ChoosenImageView">
    </ImageView>
```

My code for loading the image over the bitmap:

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent intent) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, intent);

        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            Uri imageFileUri = intent.getData();
            try {
                BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
                bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = true;
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);

                bmpFactoryOptions.inJustDecodeBounds = false;
                bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);

                alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bmp.getWidth(), bmp
                        .getHeight(), bmp.getConfig());
                canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap);
                paint = new Paint();
                paint.setColor(Color.GREEN);
                paint.setStrokeWidth(15);
                matrix = new Matrix();
                canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, matrix, paint);

                choosenImageView.setImageBitmap(alteredBitmap);
                choosenImageView.setOnTouchListener(this);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Log.v("ERROR", e.toString());
            }
        }
    }
```

My onTouch:

```
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
        int action = event.getAction();
        switch (action) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                downx = event.getX();
                downy = event.getY();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_MOVE:
                upx = event.getX();
                upy = event.getY();
                canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
                choosenImageView.invalidate();
                downx = upx;
                downy = upy;
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                upx = event.getX();
                upy = event.getY();
                canvas.drawLine(downx, downy, upx, upy, paint);
                choosenImageView.invalidate();
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Your bitmap is being scaled down to fit the image view. The touch event coordinates are relative to the image view, but when you draw on the bitmap canvas, you are drawing in bitmap coordinates (which then again gets scaled down to fit the image view, and that is what you are seeing).

You need to somehow transform between scaled coordinates and the original bitmap coordinates.  You can do that multiple ways, but one way is to scale the bitmap to the imageview right from the start (rather than rely on built-in imageview scaling). Something like this:

```
    // For full display
    float dw = currentDisplay.getWidth();
    float dh = currentDisplay.getHeight();

    // Or for image view itself (but requires correct layout setup)
    float dw = imageView.getWidth()
    float dh = imageView.getHeight();

    BitmapFactory.Options bmpFactoryOptions = new BitmapFactory.Options();
    bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(getContentResolver().openInputStream(imageFileUri), null, bmpFactoryOptions);

    // etc, etc.

    alteredBitmap = Bitmap.createScaledBitmap(bmp, dw, dh, true);
    canvas = new Canvas(alteredBitmap);
```

Comment: Hi @kaliatech, while the issue of bad placement of drawing is being resolved with your code, Im getting an issue that the image is now fit-to-page instead of scaled..
Any suggestions about it?

Comment: I don't fully understand your comment, but I suspect you used the "For full display" code sample instead of "Or for image view itself" code sample.  Another possibility is you need to play with your ImageView's ScaleType property. (https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ImageView.ScaleType). If that doesn't help you, consider posting a new question with your latest code.